# weird cocoapods issue installing a target for every pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

cocoapods for whatever reason is installing a target for every pod I have.  Before I upgraded to the newest version, there would be only 2 targets in the pod project in xcode, the main project target and the target for the tests, now I get this...

[image]

Here's my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '6.1'

target :StoryBoardsTests do
  pod 'OCMock'
  pod 'Expecta'
end

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change is documented in the 0.22.0 [release notes](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0220). It looks like it came about from [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1165). The purpose is to make what the libraries are linking to more obvious.

If this is causing an unintended sideaffect that would be another issue we'd love to hear about.